# Android In app billing

Tags: android, google-play, publish, billing, in-app-billing

I have successfully integrated the in app sample in my project and its working fine but I have not found any tutorial or document which tells that what changes we have to make in that sample for production. Currently in `requestPurchase(this, "android.test.purchased")` method its sending the parameter com.test.purchased.

I do not know what things I have to change before publishing it on android market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-implement). You need to register and publish your own product in the developer console, then change the app to use that product name. You may also want to change the sample and implement some of the security measures mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html).

Comment: Thanks for respose Nikolay... can you please tell me from where i can get the Dungeons.java file or sample??

Comment: It's in ANDROID_SDK/extras/google/market_billing/src/com/example/dungeons.